# GRANT syntax for domain\user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, active-directory, sql-grant

I'm trying to give access to an active directory user to only one specific table. I want them to be able to insert, update, delete, etc. but only for that table. I know this command:

```
GRANT Insert, Select on Tablename to user
```

But I can't figure out how to get "domain\user" to work syntax-wise. I tried:

```
GRANT Insert, Select on Tablename to domain\user
```

But I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA SE site.

Comment: @MarcB how is a syntax issue not a programming question?

Comment: @aaron: in the same way that "can't make a line of text italicize in Word" isn't a programming question, unless you're trying to programatically build a Word file via COM or whatever.

Comment: @MarcB they obviously tried `GRANT ... TO domain\user` and got `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 181
Incorrect syntax near '\'.` Are you suggesting that my answer is not a programming-related answer, but solely related to database administration? If so, I disagree 100%.

Comment: @MarcB your answer to aaron betrays the actual reason this should be closed --- don't just kick rubbish over to DBA.SE.

Comment: @MarcB if you brought this problem to your DBA he would scold you quite heavily I think.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Assuming you have created a user in this database associated with the AD login, e.g.

```
CREATE LOGIN [domain\user] FROM WINDOWS;
GO
USE your_database;
GO
CREATE USER [domain\user] FROM LOGIN [domain\user];
GO
```

Then you merely have to follow the same syntax. Because `\` is not a standard character for an identifier, you need to escape the name with `[square brackets]`:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.Tablename TO [domain\user];
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that worked! I tried all sorts of quotes, didn't even consider square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to create a role and add users to that role. Then grant permissions to that role.

```
USE database_name
GO

--1)create role 
CREATE ROLE role_name
GO

--2 create user
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'domain\user')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [domain\user] FOR LOGIN [domain\user]
END;
GO

-- 3 Add user to the role
ALTER ROLE [role_name] ADD MEMBER [domain\user]
GO

--4 Grant permissions to the role
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON dbo.Tablename TO [role_name];
```