# how to grant/deny permissions in sql server and to map the users to UserID in database User table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I need to grant permissions to a user and then to connect user with userID in a table. I have UserID Column with an ID (125845) for an example, and windows logon is SSchmidt. I want to grant and deny some permissions for this user and to connect the user with his ID. I´ve tried this but i get an error (wrong syntax where "\"):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON tbl_Auto TO DADDO_PC\SSchmidt
```

Comment: Obviously the '\' in that username is causing an error. Try wrapping it in brackets.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to wrap the username in brackets?

Comment: thanks, i have tried single quotes and wrapping it in brackets but it didnt work, now i´ve tried double quotes and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON TABLE tbl_Auto TO [DADDO_PC\SSchmidt]
```

Comment: thanks this works too, but how do i connect the user (SSchmidt) with a UserID in my database table?

Comment: Great article here on that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907859/grant-syntax-for-domain-user

Comment: Thanks, but there´s nothing about mapping a windows user to sql database ID column

Comment: Have you tried looking in the GUI under Security->Logins and finding the user that you created and mapping it that way?

Comment: I´ve tried looking in the security logins but i didn´t see any option to map the user to a value in a column