# C# EF - Cannot open database 'DB NAME' requested by the login. the login failed , login failed for user

Tags: c#, database

There are plenty of posts about this error but I could not solve my problem with the answers there.

I've made an app to run with SQL Server through Entity Framework. The app is running on my PC with no problem , but when I send it to someone he gets this error

> Cannot open database 'StorageDb' requested by the login. the login failed , login failed for user 'DESKTOP-....../User'

I've read that it has something to do with my connection string but I tried to change it and still it does not work. Here it is (in my `app.config` file):

```
<add name="Storage.Properties.Settings.StorageDbConnectionString"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StorageDb;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

My `DbContext` file:

```
public StorageDbContext() : base("StorageDb")
{
   ....
}
```

I tried removing the string in the constructor or change it but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Their user account does not have permission to access the server. Simple as that. Grant the account access.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Consider creating a database user for the application with db_reader and db_writer permissions. Then change your connectionstring to it; `connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StorageDb;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;"`

Comment: Check this one out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwqo7kbUuWQ

Comment: Your context needs to match the connection string name, try this `public StorageDbContext() : base("Storage.Properties.Settings.StorageDbConnectionString")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have `Integrated Security=True` in your connection string the application would use windows identity (of the logged in user) to connect to the database.

```
<add name="Storage.Properties.Settings.StorageDbConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StorageDb;Integrated Security=True"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

So to solve the issue, you can either grant permission to the logged in user's account as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907859/grant-syntax-for-domain-user). or update your connection string to use sql server mode of authentication. e.g

```
<add name="MyDbConn" 
        connectionString="Server=MyServer; Database=pubs; User Id=MyUser; password= P@ssw0rd"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

please refer this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx) or other msdn pages for details.